# How to use the empty signal of the Queue?

Tags: chisel

I'm using the `Queue` of the Chisel Lang in a design. Accessing the `empty` and `full` signals of the Queue could be beneficial, but since they're not part of the IO, I cannot use them. Is there any way to use those signals other than duplicating the Queue implementation and customizing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see [in Chisel code](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/blob/v3.5.3/src/main/scala/chisel3/util/Decoupled.scala#L288) :

```scala
  io.deq.valid := !empty
  io.enq.ready := !full
```

we can use enqueue and dequeue interface to know if Queue is full or empty.

If the dequeue signal `io.deq.valid` is `false.B`, then the Queue is empty (you can't «dequeue» data). And if the enqueue signal `io.enq.ready` is `false.B`, then the Queue is full (you can't push new data).